# Rails avoiding duplication of database entry(many attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, validates-uniqueness-of

Is there any way to make the model execute an error message like `flash[:notice]`??

I want to avoid entering the same data to my database twice..

```
before_save :no_duplication

private

    def no_duplication
        if CarPrice.where(:car_id => self.car_id).where(:agent_id => self.agent_id).blank?
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
```

This code stop duplicating but it doesn't send any error messages. How can I fix that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing rails flash\[:notice\] in a model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701932/accessing-rails-flashnotice-in-a-model)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer using a model validation:

```
validates :car_id, uniqueness: { scope: :agent_id }
```

Take a look at the docs for other options such as allow_nil: true, etc. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

I would also recommend adding a unique index:

```
add_index :name_of_table, [:car_id, :agent_id], unique: true
```

Comment: validates :car_id, uniqueness: { scope: :agent_id }
 you mean this line replaces my whole code??

Comment: Yes - that's what I would do. I don't see a need for your current before_save method.